# Update PostgreSQL 14 to 15 with active citus extension

Tags: postgresql, citus

I am trying to use [the official way](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/admin_guide/upgrading_citus.html#upgrading-postgres)
to upgrade from PG 14 to 15 with Citus. If I would follow these instructions, I would have upgraded PG, but not citus, since nowhere the citus111_15 rpm is being installed (CentOS 7)? I am a little bit confused about this.

It says update citus first, then postgres...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now installed postgres15 first and then did the *pg_upgrade* --check.

There is an error since the **citus** extension is missing.

So after installing citus111_15 the check looks ok.

So the citus-upgrades that have to be done first are to be done on the old major version of postgres - here 14.5.
e.g. from citus 11.0 to 11.1.4. Now the procedure is clear to me.